# Can you run `guix deploy` on other linux distributions?

Tags: debian, guix

Guix can be run on other linux distributions.
But can `guix deploy` provision machines running debian?
I think nixops requires machines to use nixos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't , the command `guix deploy` is used to manage only a guix system (GuixSD).

Syntax:

```
guix deploy file
```

The `file` is the [configuration system](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Using-the-Configuration-System.html#Using-the-Configuration-System) file (operating system declaration).

[8.15 Invoking guix deploy](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/devel/en/html_node/Invoking-guix-deploy.html)